# signalr ie9 and silverlight5 not working properly

Tags: silverlight, windows-7, internet-explorer-9, iis-7.5, signalr

I'm having this problem for about 3 days now and is driving me crazy:
I have a silverlight busyness application hosted on Windows7 Ultimate and IIS 7.5, I'm accesing the site using ie9, on my computer everything works great, I access my site locally or from another computer in the network and everything works perfectly. But there is this other computer which is outside my network, there my app is hosted on windows 7 ultimate enterprise and IIS7.5, when they try to access the site using ie9 the first time they logging signalr works great but as soon as they logout and then logging again signalr stops working.
Another difference is in ie version, I'm using update version 9.0.7 and they are using 9.0.11. So, my question is: 
Is there any known problem for signalr apps hosted in iis 7.5 and win7 enterprise and ultimate or when accessing the site using ie 9.0.7 and ie9.0.11?
I've already had to deal with the problem of not hosting the site on IIS root.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Well, now the client told me they tried on a mac with safari and had the same problem, so it seems to be a server thing...

Comment: Use Fiddler on client machine to see http traffic. Compare when they first login with their second login. You want to see the requests to URLs with "/negotiate" and "/connect"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gustavo, I've already solved the problem by updating to the latest version of SignalR, the one I had was 1.0.1, now I have 1.2.1 and the problem is gone, now is working as expected.